# Changing the default Jupyter configuration directory

Tags: python, virtualenv, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I start `jupyter-lab` from a python 3 virtual environment. On executing `jupyter --config-dir`, I can see `/Users/myusername/.jupyter`

I've edited the file `jupyter_notebook_config.py`, located in the above directory, to change the default location of user configuration directory given by: `c.LabApp.user_settings_dir` from `/Users/myusername/.jupyter/lab/user-settings` to `/Users/myusername/.config/jupyter/lab/user-settings` **to keep my home directory clean**.

But when I execute `jupyter --config-dir` again, I'm not able to see the changes. I've also tried deactivating and reactivating the python virtual environment.

How can I change `jupyter --config-dir` so that it outputs `/Users/myusername/.config/jupyter` instead of `/Users/myusername/.jupyter` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the below lines to `.zshrc` changes the jupyter (and ipython) configuration directory:

```
export IPYTHONDIR=~/.config/ipython
export JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR=~/.config/jupyter
```